# How to check if a request has post data in a Total.js controller

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, total.js

I want a solution to keep view and post actions on the same function, by verifying if the user submited some data.

My total.js controller is like this

```
# framework
exports.install = (framework) ->
  framework.route "/subscribe", subscribe
  framework.route "/subscribe", subscribe, ['post']

# subscribe form and action
subscribe = ->
  self = this
  post = self.post

  if post
    Subscriber = self.model('subscriber')
    Subscriber.save post

  self.view "form"
```

The problem is that `post` is `{}` when I'm just viewing the page (not submiting data), so it always enter on `if`.

If I compare to `{}` (`if post isnt {}`) the condition is always false, probably because `self.post` is not an empty object.

[update]

- When viewing the page:

  ```
  console.log post    #logs {}
  ```
- When submiting the form:

  ```
  console.log post    #logs { type: 1, email: "email@example.com" }
  ```

Comment: Could you log -- and show us -- what is `post` both when you are viewing the page and when you are submitting data ?

Comment: I've updated the question with the logs you requested, @SylvainLeroux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't clearly understand `is`/`isnt`. Look at that example:

```
coffee> {} is {}
false
```

Surprising ? Not if you know the `is` test is two variable references the *same* object. Not *identical*. Really the *same* object:

```
coffee> obj1 = {}
{}
coffee> obj2 = obj1
{}
coffee> obj1 is obj2
true
```

---

You might then go to `==` in order to test for *equivalence*.  But:

```
coffee> {} == {}
false
```

Unfortunately, [JavaScript does not provide a easy way to test for *object equality*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201471/2363712).

In you case, you should resort on some trick. Like:

```
if (i for i in post).length == 0
  ...
```

Or maybe check for the presence of some *key* field:

```
if 'type' not of post
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple checking:

```js
function some_action_in_controller() {
    var self = this;
    // self.body is same as self.post
    var isEmpty = Object.keys(self.body).length === 0);
    self.json({ result: isEmpty }); 
}
```